# Two OEM Windows for one computer?

Tags: windows, virtualization, license

It's OK, if I buy two OEM license of Windows for one computer and one of them install normal and second install into virtual machine on that computer?

Answer (score 2):

One license is enough. They wont sue you in any way because the Windows 7 EULA allows you to use one license on a normal partition, and on a virtual partition.

Comment: where did you read this?? according to Microsoft, Windows 7 is currently in developement and the EULA is not available as of yet ... coming soon: http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/eula.aspx

Comment: besides, you can activate windows only once. i think your answer is lacking legal soundness.

Comment: It was reported that the Win7 license will allow 3 virtual machines on the same physical machine with the same license. Whether this is the case, I don't know.

Comment: @Molly, windows 7 was released a few days ago at retail, and has been available to some corporate and university customers for a month or so before that.

Comment: exactly @harrymc and @bdonlan. It is certainly not completely sure if it is like it is, but yes, there were indeed reports of using virtual machines on one physical.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use an OEM license in a virtual machine. If you change the config of the machine or you delete/recreate it your license will be destroyed with the machine. It's a bit more expensive but to avoid issues I would only recommend retail or upgrade licenses for virtual machine use.

Excerpt from Windows 7 Home Premium OEM EULA(This section is the same for retail/OEM and HP/Pro versions)

> d.  Use with Virtualization Technologies. Instead of using the software directly on the licensed 
>   computer, you may install and use the software within only one virtual (or otherwise emulated) 
>   hardware system on the licensed computer. When used in a virtualized environment, content 
>   protected by digital rights management technology, BitLocker or any full volume disk drive 
>   encryption technology may not be as secure as protected content not in a virtualized 
>   environment. You should comply with all domestic and international laws that apply to such 
>   protected content.

You can find the whole EULA here http://www.microsoft.com/about/legal/useterms/default.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I'd have to disagree that the EULA allows you use one license on the computer AND on one VM.  If you read it carefully it says "Instead of using the software directly on the licensed computer, you may install & use the software within only one virtual..blah blah)"  The keywords here are INSTEAD OF.  In other words, it's saying you can install your OEM copy on a VM INSTEAD OF using it directly on the physical computer.  So you can do it one way or the other, but not both ways.

Answer (score 1):

Yes!

You can use a windows licence within virtualised hardware.